# "double(*)(string, double, double)" to "double" conversion error when trying to pass a function C++

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to c++ and I am writing a program that has a struct, and 3 functions named win_percentage, Wins_losses, and winning_teams. The object of this assignment is to create a program that prints out 13 school teams, their records, and then to print out the teams who are over .500 in wins.

I keep getting an error that says:

> **cannot convert 'double (*)(std::__cxx11::string, double, double) {aka double (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string, double, double)}' to
>   'double' for argument '4' to 'void wins_losses(std::__cxx11::string,
>   double, double, double)'
>
>   wins_losses(school1.name,school1.wins,school1.losses,
>   win_percentage);**

The problem occurs when I am trying to pass the win_percentage function into the other functions. How am I able to fix this problem? please help lol

here is my code. (ps I will make a for loop for this program)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct Team 
{
  string name;
  int wins;
  int losses;
};

double win_percentage (string , double , double );
void wins_losses (string , double , double , double );
void winning_teams (string , double , double , double );

int main() {
  Team school1 = {"Bethune-Cookman", 11, 3};
  Team school2 = {"Coppin State", 5, 9};
  Team school3 = {"Delaware State", 1, 13};
  Team school4 = {"Florida A&M", 6, 8};
  Team school5 = {"Hampton", 11, 4};
  Team school6 = {"Howard", 6, 8};
  Team school7 = {"Maryland Eastern Shore", 2, 12};
  Team school8 = {"Morgan State", 6, 8};
  Team school9 = {"North Carolina A&T", 10, 4};
  Team school10 = {"North Carolina Central", 8, 6};
  Team school11 = {"Norfolk State", 10, 4};
  Team school12 = {"Savannah State", 10, 4};
  Team school13 = {"South Carolina State", 6, 8};




  cout<< "MEAC MENS BASKETBALL TEAMS CONFERENCE STANDINGS"<< endl;

  cout<< school1.name<<" "<<school1.wins<<"-"<<school1.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school2.name<<" "<<school2.wins<<"-"<<school2.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school3.name<<" "<<school3.wins<<"-"<<school3.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school4.name<<" "<<school4.wins<<"-"<<school4.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school5.name<<" "<<school5.wins<<"-"<<school5.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school6.name<<" "<<school6.wins<<"-"<<school6.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school7.name<<" "<<school7.wins<<"-"<<school7.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school8.name<<" "<<school8.wins<<"-"<<school8.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school9.name<<" "<<school9.wins<<"-"<<school9.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school10.name<<" "<<school10.wins<<"-"<<school10.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school11.name<<" "<<school11.wins<<"-"<<school11.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school12.name<<" "<<school12.wins<<"-"<<school12.losses<< endl;
  cout<< school13.name<<" "<<school13.wins<<"-"<<school13.losses<< endl;




  cout<<"TEAMS WINNING PERCENTAGE"<<endl;
  win_percentage(school1.name,school1.wins,school1.losses);
  win_percentage(school2.name,school2.wins,school2.losses);
  win_percentage(school3.name,school3.wins,school3.losses);
  win_percentage(school4.name,school4.wins,school4.losses);
  win_percentage(school5.name,school5.wins,school5.losses);
  win_percentage(school6.name,school6.wins,school6.losses);
  win_percentage(school7.name,school7.wins,school7.losses);
  win_percentage(school8.name,school8.wins,school8.losses);
  win_percentage(school9.name,school9.wins,school9.losses);
  win_percentage(school10.name,school10.wins,school10.losses);
  win_percentage(school11.name,school11.wins,school11.losses);
  win_percentage(school12.name,school12.wins,school12.losses);
  win_percentage(school13.name,school13.wins,school13.losses);
  cout<<"TEAMS WITH WINNING RECORDS"<<endl;

  wins_losses(school1.name,school1.wins,school1.losses, win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school2.name,school2.wins,school2.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school3.name,school3.wins,school3.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school4.name,school4.wins,school4.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school5.name,school5.wins,school5.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school6.name,school6.wins,school6.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school7.name,school7.wins,school7.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school8.name,school8.wins,school8.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school9.name,school9.wins,school9.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school10.name,school10.wins,school10.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school11.name,school11.wins,school11.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school12.name,school12.wins,school12.losses,win_percentage);
  wins_losses(school13.name,school13.wins,school13.losses,win_percentage);

  winning_teams(school1.name,school1.wins,school1.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school2.name,school2.wins,school2.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school3.name,school3.wins,school3.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school4.name,school4.wins,school4.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school5.name,school5.wins,school5.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school6.name,school6.wins,school6.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school7.name,school7.wins,school7.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school8.name,school8.wins,school8.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school9.name,school9.wins,school9.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school10.name,school10.wins,school10.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school11.name,school11.wins,school11.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school12.name,school12.wins,school12.losses,win_percentage);
  winning_teams(school13.name,school13.wins,school13.losses,win_percentage);

  return 0;
}

double win_percentage(string a, double b, double c){
  double x;
  x == b / (b + c);
  cout<< a<<" "<<x<<endl;

}
void wins_losses( string e, double f, double g, double h){

   cout<< e<< "Record is"<<f<<"-"<<g<< h<<endl;
}
void winning_teams(string w, int f, int y, double z){
  if ( z >.500){
    cout<< w<<" "<<f<< "-"<<y<< " "<< z<< endl;

  }
}
```

Comment: `x == b / (b + c);` doesn't do an assignment... Also I don't understand why you are passing a function that doesn't even return a double in place of a plain double variable.

Comment: Look at the last parameter that you're passing to `wins_losses`.  Is it a double?  Or a function?  Your error is telling you that you don't seem to be sure.

Comment: Your subject is confusing, there is no `double *` to `double` conversion in your code.

Answer (score 3):

I notice a few problems here. First:

```
double win_percentage(string a, double b, double c){
  double x;
  x == b / (b + c);
  cout<< a<<" "<<x<<endl;

}
```

The function doesn't:

1. Assign to the variable `x`, since it is using the equality operator.
2. Return a value, so the caller of the function cannot access `x`. This is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) since there is no return from a non-void function.

Next:

```
winning_teams(school1.name,school1.wins,school1.losses,win_percentage);
```

This call attempts to pass a function pointer to a function that expects a double. Instead, use the function pointer syntax or even better, use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

However, I doubt that you actually need to pass a function here. If you want to pass the *result* of the function, then do:

```
winning_teams(school1.name,
    school1.wins,
    school1.losses,
    win_percentage(/* Parameters to the function */));
```

Comment: 2. Not only can the caller not access `x`, but the behaviour of the program is undefined due to not returning from the non void function.

Comment: @DWILLS If you found this answer helpful, please don't hesitate in marking it correct by clicking the checkmark below this answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `wins_losses`, you pass `win_percentage` as a parameter:

```
wins_losses(school1.name,school1.wins,school1.losses, win_percentage);
```

Function `wins_losses` expects a `double`, but you pass a reference to a function, i.e. `win_percentage`.

That's why.

So either you call `win_percentage` such that its return value is used as parameter then, or you pass a double value:

```
wins_losses(school1.name,school1.wins,school1.losses, win_percentage(school1.name,school1.wins,school1.losses));

wins_losses(school1.name,school1.wins,school1.losses,5.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the comparing operator instead of the assignment operator in win_percentage

```
double win_percentage(string a, double b, double c){
      double x;
      x == b / (b + c);
      cout<< a<<" "<<x<<endl;

    }
```

Try to use: 
x = (b/(b+c))

Comment: This does not answer the question, so should be a comment